# SQL dynamic pivot for goals

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

Let's assume I have a table with the following rows and columns

```
EmpCode    Empname   Goals
-------    ----     ------
101        kiran     readsql
101        kiran     coding
101        kiran     readcss
102        rohit     coding
102        rohit     readjava
103        pradi     do nothing
```

I want to display above table in below format:

```
EmpCode    Empname   Goal1     Goal2    Goal3
-------    ----     ------     ------   ------ 
101        kiran     readsql   coding   readcss
101        rohit     coding    readjava
103        pradi     do nothing
```

The field goals is dynamic, please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the example [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).  I think you may have a problem if the number of goals doesn't have a maximum.

Comment: hi bones ,in the above example he is using count of weeks to group, but in my case filed goal is varchar

Comment: It's not going to answer your question specifically, but until someone else chimes in you can probably adapt it to what you're doing and find your own answer.  It beats waiting around hitting "Refresh".  :o)

Comment: I'm wondering why the EmpCode in the second line of your expected output is `101` and not `102` .

Comment: Sorry it's typo mistake

Comment: @bones .. Thanks for ur comments.. :-) I am new to this concept so not able to map my requirement with existing example wic u have mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,EmpCode INT,Empname VARCHAR(2566),Goals VARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO #tt(EmpCode,Empname,Goals)VALUES
    (101,'kiran','readsql'),
    (101,'kiran','coding'),
    (101,'kiran','readcss'),
    (102,'rohit','coding'),
    (102,'rohit','readjava'),
    (103,'pradi','do nothing');

DECLARE @goal_cols NVARCHAR(MAX)=STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT N',Goal'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY empcode ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR(3))
    FROM #tt
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
);

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'
    SELECT *    
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                EmpCode,Empname,Goals,
                goal_id=''Goal''+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY empcode ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR(3))
            FROM 
                #tt
        ) AS s
        PIVOT(MAX(Goals) FOR goal_id IN ('+@goal_cols+')) AS p
    ORDER BY EmpCode;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt;

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------+
| EmpCode | Empname |   Goal1    |  Goal2   |  Goal3  |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------+
|     101 | kiran   | readsql    | coding   | readcss |
|     102 | rohit   | coding     | readjava | NULL    |
|     103 | pradi   | do nothing | NULL     | NULL    |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: awesome ... thanks TT:-)