# SQL Server : multiple rows (with multiple columns) pivoted into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a question around turning multiple rows (with multiple columns) into a single row with columns.

e.g.

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  
1     type1 123  
1     type2 456
```

Output should be:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  
1     type1  123  type2 456
```

I have tried looking into SQL Server recursive and Pivot but not sure which would be the correct way to proceed.

Another requirement would be to keep it as dynamic as possible.

Comment: You always have two types? or they are unlimited

Comment: Maximum could be for 5  and col3 will always be different

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35350343/243373) I gave on a somewhat similar question, see if you can make it work for your case.

Comment: Hi TT, 
The solution works well for a single column, but in my case there are two columns which needs to be transposed. Since pivot only gives  you option to use aggregate functions, it somehow doesn't seem to work on two columns at once.