# Turn output from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Lets say i have a table Sales

With this select i get this.

```
SELECT CustID, Date, ArtikelNr FROM Sales

CustID  Date         ArtikelNr
1       23.02.2016   50
1       14.02.2016   40
2       22.02.2016   40
1       24.02.2016   50
```

Now i want the Output like this.

```
CustID  ArtikelNr Date1        Date2       Date3  ... DateN
1       50        23.02.2016   24.02.2016
1       40        14.02.2016
2       50        24.02.2016
```

How can i do this?

Comment: So you want a dynamic number of columns, depending on the table's different date values?

Comment: Can you add some more rows to the sample data and result

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/). It might help you come up with a query. Sadly SQLFiddle for SQL server is not working so I can't try it.

Comment: @jarlh Yes that's exactly what i mean.

Comment: @MotoGP This is not how my table Looks like i just wanted to Show in simple how i mean

Comment: check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1011591/Dynamic-Pivot-Query-in-SQL-Server)

Comment: You will have to create a procedure for this. I don't think you can accomplish this with just a query. You may need to construct a temporary table with the data you want to accomplish this.

Comment: Look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35350343/243373) I gave to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35347342/243373) as an example. It's similar except you would be partitioning `CustId` and `ArtikelNr`, and ordering by `[Date]`.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's perhaps a problem with either your input data, or example output, since your last output row doesn't seem to match any of your inputs.

I think you're asking for a dynamic pivot, something like this:

### Test data

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
CREATE TABLE #Test (CustId INT, Date DATE, ArtikelNr INT)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES
(1,'23.02.2016',50),
(1,'14.02.2016',40),
(2,'22.02.2016',40),
(1,'24.02.2016',50)
```

### Query

```
DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Cols= ISNULL(@Cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(RN) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustId, ArtikelNr ORDER BY CustId) RN FROM #Test) Z

SET @Query = 
  N'SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustId, ArtikelNr ORDER BY CustId) RN FROM #Test) A
    PIVOT ( MIN(DATE) FOR RN IN ('+@Cols+')) PVT
ORDER BY CustId, ArtikelNr DESC'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query

CustId      ArtikelNr   1          2
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
1           50          2016-02-23 2016-02-24
1           40          2016-02-14 NULL
2           40          2016-02-22 NULL
```